# Exporting large dataset to any supporting file format, for creating a database on MySQL/Postgresql

Tags: sql, database

What should be the approach to export data from clickhouse database. I want to export it into any file which supports MBs of data and create a new database locally(MySQL/PostgreSQL) for learning and project purposes.

I am using DBeaver to query and export, to .csv but process terminates itself when it reaches max rows limit.
Please suggest.

Comment: did you try https://github.com/AlexAkulov/clickhouse-backup ?

Comment: ah I'm sorry, I missed the part about mysql. what I'd do is create a very simple js/python script that select * from TABLE_NAME and INSERT it to second database